# Why GraphQL is termed as Query Language for "API" and not any Data?

Tags: graphql

I have just started reading about GraphQL and the description says it's a query language for API. Why is it termed as query language for API? Can't Graphql API service directly talk to Database or any other data source directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just poor word choice. Elsewhere on the official site, they refer to it as a "query language for *your* API" (emphasis mine), which is a bit less ambiguous. Other API endpoints can certainly be used as data sources for your GraphQL service, as can databases, file systems or just about anything. However, the intended meaning is that **GraphQL can be used to create an API**, not that it's used exclusively to interface with other APIs.

Here's a more technical and complete description from [the spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Overview):

> GraphQL is a query language designed to build client applications by providing an intuitive and flexible syntax and system for describing their data requirements and interactions.
>
> GraphQL is not a programming language capable of arbitrary computation, but is instead a language used to query application servers that have capabilities defined in this specification. GraphQL does not mandate a particular programming language or storage system for application servers that implement it. Instead, application servers take their capabilities and map them to a uniform language, type system, and philosophy that GraphQL encodes. This provides a unified interface friendly to product development and a powerful platform for tool‐building.